# Can't stop explosion animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made an explosion animation but I can't stop it from executing. I've tried using `setInterval` but it doesn't seem to work. What might be wrong with this code?

```js
function grow() {
  setInterval(function() {
    balloon = document.querySelector('.balloon');
    balloon.style.width = '200px';
    balloon.style.height = '200px';
    balloon.style.transition = '3s';

    setInterval(function() {
      balloon.style.display = 'none';
      explode(balloon);
    }, 2000);

  }, 2000);
};

grow();

var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.balloon');

function explode(e) {
  var x = e.clientX
  var y = e.clientY
  var c = document.createElement('canvas')
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
  var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio
  var particles = []

  document.body.appendChild(c)

  c.style.position = 'absolute'
  c.style.left = (x - 100) + 'px'
  c.style.top = (y - 100) + 'px'
  c.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
  c.style.width = 200 + 'px'
  c.style.height = 200 + 'px'
  c.width = 200 * ratio
  c.height = 200 * ratio

  function Particle() {
    return {
      x: c.width / 2,
      y: c.height / 2,
      radius: r(20, 30),
      color: 'rgb(' + [r(0, 255), r(0, 255), r(0, 255)].join(',') + ')',
      rotation: r(0, 360, true),
      speed: r(8, 12),
      friction: 0.9,
      opacity: r(0, 0.5, true),
      yVel: 0,
      gravity: 0.1
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; ++i < 25;) {
    particles.push(Particle())
  }

  console.log(particles[0])

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)

    particles.forEach(function(p, i) {

      angleTools.moveOnAngle(p, p.speed)

      p.opacity -= 0.01
      p.speed *= p.friction
      p.radius *= p.friction

      p.yVel += p.gravity
      p.y += p.yVel

      if (p.opacity < 0) return
      if (p.radius < 0) return

      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.globalAlpha = p.opacity
      ctx.fillStyle = p.color
      ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
      ctx.fill()

    })

  }

  ;
  (function renderLoop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)
    render()

  })()
}
var angleTools = {
  getAngle: function(t, n) {
    var a = n.x - t.x,
      e = n.y - t.y;
    return Math.atan2(e, a) / Math.PI * 180
  },
  getDistance: function(t, n) {
    var a = t.x - n.x,
      e = t.y - n.y;
    return Math.sqrt(a * a + e * e)
  },
  moveOnAngle: function(t, n) {
    var a = this.getOneFrameDistance(t, n);
    t.x += a.x, t.y += a.y
  },
  getOneFrameDistance: function(t, n) {
    return {
      x: n * Math.cos(t.rotation * Math.PI / 180),
      y: n * Math.sin(t.rotation * Math.PI / 180)
    }
  }
};

function r(a, b, c) {
  return parseFloat((Math.random() * ((a ? a : 1) - (b ? b : 0)) + (b ? b : 0)).toFixed(c ? c : 0));
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: hsl(70, 31%, 85%);
}

.explosion {
  position: absolute; // required if positioned on click else 'relative'
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  pointer-events: none; // make it clickable trhough
  // particle styling
  .particle {
    position: absolute; // required  
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: pop 1s reverse forwards; // required
  }
}

// animation for particle fly away from the cursor
@keyframes pop {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 103px;
  height: 125px;
  background: hsl(215, 50%, 65%);
  border-radius: 80%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  margin: 20px 30px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: balloons 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

@keyframes balloons {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-4deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-25px) rotate(4deg);
  }
}

.balloon:before {
  content: "▲";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: hsl(215, 30%, 50%);
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Comment: It has given me a more understanding between setTimeout and setInterval in how to use them. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

```js
function grow() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    balloon = document.querySelector('.balloon');
    balloon.style.width = '200px';
    balloon.style.height = '200px';
    balloon.style.transition = '3s';

    setTimeout(function() {
      balloon.style.display = 'none';
      explode(balloon);
    }, 2000);

  }, 2000);
};

grow();

var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.balloon');

function explode(e) {
  var x = e.clientX
  var y = e.clientY
  var c = document.createElement('canvas')
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
  var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio
  var particles = []

  document.body.appendChild(c)

  c.style.position = 'absolute'
  c.style.left = (x - 100) + 'px'
  c.style.top = (y - 100) + 'px'
  c.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
  c.style.width = 200 + 'px'
  c.style.height = 200 + 'px'
  c.width = 200 * ratio
  c.height = 200 * ratio

  function Particle() {
    return {
      x: c.width / 2,
      y: c.height / 2,
      radius: r(20, 30),
      color: 'rgb(' + [r(0, 255), r(0, 255), r(0, 255)].join(',') + ')',
      rotation: r(0, 360, true),
      speed: r(8, 12),
      friction: 0.9,
      opacity: r(0, 0.5, true),
      yVel: 0,
      gravity: 0.1
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; ++i < 25;) {
    particles.push(Particle())
  }

  console.log(particles[0])

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)

    particles.forEach(function(p, i) {

      angleTools.moveOnAngle(p, p.speed)

      p.opacity -= 0.01
      p.speed *= p.friction
      p.radius *= p.friction

      p.yVel += p.gravity
      p.y += p.yVel

      if (p.opacity < 0) return
      if (p.radius < 0) return

      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.globalAlpha = p.opacity
      ctx.fillStyle = p.color
      ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
      ctx.fill()

    })

  }

  ;
  (function renderLoop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)
    render()

  })()
}
var angleTools = {
  getAngle: function(t, n) {
    var a = n.x - t.x,
      e = n.y - t.y;
    return Math.atan2(e, a) / Math.PI * 180
  },
  getDistance: function(t, n) {
    var a = t.x - n.x,
      e = t.y - n.y;
    return Math.sqrt(a * a + e * e)
  },
  moveOnAngle: function(t, n) {
    var a = this.getOneFrameDistance(t, n);
    t.x += a.x, t.y += a.y
  },
  getOneFrameDistance: function(t, n) {
    return {
      x: n * Math.cos(t.rotation * Math.PI / 180),
      y: n * Math.sin(t.rotation * Math.PI / 180)
    }
  }
};

function r(a, b, c) {
  return parseFloat((Math.random() * ((a ? a : 1) - (b ? b : 0)) + (b ? b : 0)).toFixed(c ? c : 0));
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: hsl(70, 31%, 85%);
}

.explosion {
  position: absolute; // required if positioned on click else 'relative'
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  pointer-events: none; // make it clickable trhough
  // particle styling
  .particle {
    position: absolute; // required  
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: pop 1s reverse forwards; // required
  }
}

// animation for particle fly away from the cursor
@keyframes pop {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.balloon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 103px;
  height: 125px;
  background: hsl(215, 50%, 65%);
  border-radius: 80%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  margin: 20px 30px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: balloons 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

@keyframes balloons {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-4deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-25px) rotate(4deg);
  }
}

.balloon:before {
  content: "▲";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: hsl(215, 30%, 50%);
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class="balloon"></div>
```